# High-variance Training Loss and Constant Validation Loss When Training Transformer-based CV Model In PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, neural-network, computer-vision, huggingface-transformers

I am attempting to fine-tune a transformer-based Computer Vision model, specifically the [`microsoft/swinv2-large-patch4-window12to16-192to256-22kto1k-ft` model, available through HuggingFace](https://huggingface.co/microsoft/swinv2-large-patch4-window12to16-192to256-22kto1k-ft).

My training process is somewhat complex. It involves:

1. Training on both a synthetic image data set and a subset of ImageNet
2. Using Low-rank Adaptation to reduce the number of trainable parameters ([paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.09685), [HuggingFace docs](https://huggingface.co/docs/peft/task_guides/image_classification_lora#image-classification-using-lora))

The model I am training has a primary output head for image classification, and 8 supplementary output heads that predict properties that are annotated on the synthetic data set, these include features like the pose of the object and the lighting direction.

The training process uses both real and synthetic images, and in each batch the model parameters are first trained on a batch of synthetic images. This is done using one optimiser, that trains all trainable parameters of the model. Following this, the model is trained on a batch of ImageNet images with a *different* optimiser that affects only the parameters of the primary classification head. (The other parameters are not labelled in ImageNet.) This approach is implemented as a method of *replay* to avoid *catastrophic forgetting*.

Unfortunately I am running into a problem that I haven't been able to resolve. Looking at the training and validation accuracies and losses that I am logging to Tensorboard I find that the accuracy on the training data for every task *decreases* over the epochs, and loss *increases*. At the same time, the validation accuracy *and* loss on both real and synthetic tasks remains **completely constant**.

[Some sample plots over 14 epochs of training are shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcNTm.png)

All tasks are discretized, and the loss functions used for all tasks are Categorical Cross-entropy. For the multi-task loss, these are combined using a weighted sum over all classes. For the ImageNet-only loss the raw CCEL is used.

A simplified version of the code (with comments describing omitted steps) is provided below:

```py
# Custom data sets are defined and initialised

# Custom model is defined and initialised

# Custom loss functions are defined and initialised

# Base model is loaded from HuggingFace and passed into the custom model

# LoRA is applied to the model
config = LoraConfig(
    r=20,
    lora_alpha=20,
    target_modules=["query", "value"],
    lora_dropout=0.2,
    bias="none",
    modules_to_save=[
        "dense_layer",
        "additional_dense_layer",
        "classifier",
        # Names of the other output layers
    ],
)
model = get_peft_model(model, config)

# Model is distributed over 3 GPUs using DistributedDataParallel

# The two optimisers are created
# One optimiser for updating all parameters on synthetic images
all_parameters = model.parameters()
optimizer_all = torch.optim.Adam(all_parameters, lr=0.01)

# And one for when only updating the classification head on ImageNet images
lora_parameters = (
    param
    for name, param in model.module.named_parameters()
    if ("lora_A" in name or "lora_B" in name)
)
imagenet_parameters = chain(
    lora_parameters,
    model.module.classifier.parameters(),
    model.module.dense_layer.parameters(),
    model.module.additional_dense_layer.parameters(),
)
optimizer_imagenet = torch.optim.Adam(imagenet_parameters, lr=0.01)

# Initialize the StepLR schedulers
scheduler_all = StepLR(optimizer_all, step_size=3, gamma=0.5)
scheduler_imagenet = StepLR(optimizer_imagenet, step_size=3, gamma=0.5)


# Training loop (many logging steps omitted)
for epoch in range(start_epoch, args.stop_epoch):
    # Set the epoch for DistributedSampler
    synth_train_dl.sampler.set_epoch(epoch)
    imagenet_train_dl.sampler.set_epoch(epoch)

    for i, (synth_batch, imagenet_batch) in enumerate(
        zip(synth_train_dl, imagenet_train_dl)
    ):
        ###################
        # Synthetic stage

        # Move the batch tensors to the same device as the model
        synth_batch = {k: v.to(rank) for k, v in synth_batch.items()}

        # Zero the gradients
        optimizer_all.zero_grad()

        # Perform the forward pass
        synth_outputs = model(synth_batch["image"])

        # Compute the loss
        synth_loss = multi_loss_fn(synth_outputs, synth_batch)

        # Perform the backward pass
        synth_loss.backward()

        # Update the weights
        optimizer_all.step()

        ###################
        # ImageNet stage

        # Move the batch tensors to the same device as the model
        imagenet_batch = {k: v.to(rank) for k, v in imagenet_batch.items()}

        # Zero the gradients
        optimizer_imagenet.zero_grad()

        # Perform the forward pass
        imagenet_outputs = model(imagenet_batch["image"])

        # Compute the loss
        imagenet_loss = single_loss_fn(imagenet_outputs, imagenet_batch)

        # Perform the backward pass
        imagenet_loss.backward()

        # Update the weights
        optimizer_imagenet.step()

        # Step the schedulers
        scheduler_all.step()
        scheduler_imagenet.step()

    # After each epoch, evaluate the model on the validation set
    model.eval()
    val_task_losses = {task: 0 for task in multi_loss_fn.weights.keys()}
    val_task_accuracies = {task: 0 for task in multi_loss_fn.weights.keys()}

    with torch.no_grad():
        val_loss = 0
        imagenet_loss = 0
        for i, (synth_batch, imagenet_batch) in enumerate(
            zip(synth_val_dl, imagenet_val_dl)
        ):
            ###################
            # Synthetic validation

            # Move the batch tensors to the same device as the model
            synth_batch = {k: v.to(rank) for k, v in synth_batch.items()}

            synth_outputs = model(synth_batch["image"])
            loss = multi_loss_fn(synth_outputs, synth_batch)
            val_loss += loss.item()

            # Log loss and accuracy for each task on the validation set
            for task in multi_loss_fn.weights.keys():
                task_loss = multi_loss_fn.loss_fn(
                    synth_outputs[task], synth_batch[task]
                )
                task_acc = compute_accuracy(synth_outputs[task], synth_batch[task])
                val_task_losses[task] += task_loss.item()
                val_task_accuracies[task] += task_acc

            ###################
            # ImageNet validation

            # Move the batch tensors to the same device as the model
            imagenet_batch = {k: v.to(rank) for k, v in imagenet_batch.items()}

            imagenet_outputs = model(imagenet_batch["image"])
            loss = single_loss_fn(imagenet_outputs, imagenet_batch)
            imagenet_loss += loss.item()

        for task in multi_loss_fn.weights.keys():
            avg_task_loss = val_task_losses[task] / len(synth_val_dl)
            avg_task_acc = val_task_accuracies[task] / len(synth_val_dl)
            writer.add_scalar(f"Loss/val/{task}", avg_task_loss, epoch)
            writer.add_scalar(f"Accuracy/val/{task}", avg_task_acc, epoch)

        # Write the overall validation loss to TensorBoard
        val_loss /= len(synth_val_dl)
        writer.add_scalar("Synthetic Loss/val", val_loss, epoch)
        imagenet_loss /= len(imagenet_val_dl)
        writer.add_scalar("ImageNet Loss/val", imagenet_loss, epoch)

        # Print the validation loss
        print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}/{args.stop_epoch}, Validation Loss: {val_loss}")

    # Save the model parameters
    save_checkpoint = {
        "epoch": epoch + 1,
        "model_state_dict": model.state_dict(),
        "all_optimizer_state_dict": optimizer_all.state_dict(),
        "single_optimizer_state_dict": optimizer_imagenet.state_dict(),
    }
    torch.save(save_checkpoint, f"checkpoints/checkpoint_epoch_{epoch+1}.pth")

    model.train()
```

Unfortunately the process of deploying and training this model is very slow, and I have little margin remaining for trial and error. I'd greatly appreciate anyone pointing out what would cause this issue in my code, and will gladly provide more information.

Initially I expected that my learning rate was too low, and that this was resulting in the parameters not being changed sufficiently, however I am now starting with a learning rate of 0.01, which I believe is quite large, and am still seeing the same problem.

The fact that the validation loss is *exactly* the same between epochs leads me to believe that the model is not training *at all*. This seems plausible given the results, since the data sets are shuffled during training, which could result in the high variance in training loss, however I don't see why this would be the case with my model. I am also confident that the sets of parameters passed to the optimisers are non-empty.

I fear that this could be a simple oversight due to my inexperience, and again would greatly appreciate any help.